# Клонирование контента jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет, нужна помощь:

**Есть контент вида**

```
<ul> 
  <li class="disds"><img src=".jpg">
    <div class="bluur" style="font-size:1.0em; "> <span class="bluurspan" style="display:none;"> <p>Все здорово! Процветания и удачи!</p> </span> </div>
  </li> 
  <li class="disds"><img src=".jpg">
    <div class="bluur" style="font-size:1.0em; "> <span class="bluurspan" style="display:none;"> <p>Блаблабла</p> </span> </div>
  </li>     
</ul>
```

**Есть скрытое окно, которое показывается по клику на картинку**

```
 <div class="eeeew">
   <div class="sadasd2">
     Сюда нужно клонировать контент
   </div>
 </div>
```

**Как клонировать скрытый текст (.bluurspan) в блок .eeeew?**

Comment: И что? Есть они, что дальше?

Comment: $( ".hello" ).clone().appendTo( ".goodbye" ) || `jQuery('ul li span.bluurspan').click(function() { var clone = jQuery(this).html(); jQuery('.sadasd2').html(clone);  })`

Comment: что значит _клонировать контент_? Что именно нужно вставить в _sadasd2_?

Comment: @grundy вот этот <span class="bluurspan" style="display:none;"> <p>Блаблабла</p> </span>

Comment: Добавь это непосредственно в вопрос. Точно нужен именно `span` а не просто текст из него?

Comment: @Grundy нужно отображать  <p>Блаблабла</p> конкретного элемента по которому был клик.

Comment: @Mimzik, определись что именно нужно показывать, и добавь это в свой вопрос. Сейчас непонятно что именно ты хочешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажатие обрабатывать можно через [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) и дальше через [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ищем нужный элемент:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.disds').click(function() {
    var content = $(this).find('.bluurspan').html();
    $('.sadasd2').html(content)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="disds">
    <img src=".jpg">
    <div class="bluur" style="font-size:1.0em; "> <span class="bluurspan" style="display:none;"> <p>Все здорово! Процветания и удачи!</p> </span> 
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="disds">
    <img src=".jpg">
    <div class="bluur" style="font-size:1.0em; "> <span class="bluurspan" style="display:none;"> <p>Блаблабла</p> </span> 
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="eeeew">
  <div class="sadasd2">
    Сюда нужно клонировать контент
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. В js только начинаю вникать =)